# UICollectionView space between images

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I have this problem. I UICollectionView with a component of the images. I want to add all the images with no space between them. All attributes in ispector UICollectionView component values ​​are 0. I can not understand why sempr remains a space between them: (
Can you help? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  self.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
  self.minimumInteritemSpacing=0;
```

use these in `init` method of `CollectionViewLayout`

Comment: sorry my  interface class is @interface CollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate> this is not found    self.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
  self.minimumInteritemSpacing=0;

Comment: ok thanks I made it through this example. Thanks for the reply.https://github.com/jayslu/JSPintDemo